# URISyntaxException HttpGet

Tags: java, httpclient, http-get

I want to do a request to an url which contains a parameter value that should not be encoded (because the page throws invalid query if I encode it) and has the character '%'. The browser allows it but the Httpclient throws URISyntaxException.
Url example: http://www.jobkorea.co.kr/List_GG/GG_ADV_Search_List.asp?Kwd_Sel=%uC9D1

What could I do to avoid this exception?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your url

```
String url = "your url here"

URI uri= new URI(url);

String finalUrl= uri.toASCIIString();
```

or

[Encode you URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
URLEncoder.encode("your url here", "ISO-8859-1");
```

//then make a request

Comment: But, if I encode the url, the original page throws an invalid query exception. Try http://www.jobkorea.co.kr/List_GG/GG_ADV_Search_List.asp?Kwd_Sel=%25uC9D1 instead of http://www.jobkorea.co.kr/List_GG/GG_ADV_Search_List.asp?Kwd_Sel=%uC9D1